# Bug in custom hook for fetching local json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am not able to find where is the issue with this custom hook?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const SAMPLE_DATA_URL = "../feed/sample.json";

const useFetch = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const doFetch = async () => {
      setLoading(true);

      await fetch(SAMPLE_DATA_URL)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(jsonData => {
          setResponse(jsonData);
        })
        .catch(err => setError(err))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    };
    doFetch();
  },[]);

  return { response, error, loading };
};
export default useFetch;
```

on network tab I can see 200 OK but the preview is saying "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." and also the response is html of my index screen. I checked javascript in browser is allowed and the json file is a valid json.

on return object I am getting error: true

Where its been used

```
    import React from "react";
import styles from "./Series.module.css";
import { TitleBar } from "../../atoms";
import {useFetch} from '../../utils';

const Series = () => {

const { response, loading, error }  = useFetch();


  return (
    <div >
      <TitleBar>Popular Series</TitleBar>
      <div className={styles.content}>
      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {error && <p>Oops, Something went wrong...</p>}
      {response && <p>response</p>}
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};



export default Series;
```

Comment: How are you calling `useFetch` and from where?

Comment: Can you also post how you use it ?

Comment: It's edited to include where its been used

Comment: Open `../feed/sample.json` in a browser and I bet it's not json but html. If it's a static file then why not just import it?

Comment: How it works if you fetch a web Url? May be because of security issue browser blocks reading from user hard drive by filename.  Also, this hook has an issue because it doesn't have clean up function. If component unmount during fetching it will throw an error because still async function wants to setState while component doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: hmmmm, when I used a web url it works fine.... how to work around to be able to read from file

Comment: I tried it both with a custom JSON file and a REST API and both work fine. Make sure you're using the correct path for the file. [Here's a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetching-stuff-with-custom-usefetch-hook-x16b3).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CRA, you can put your `sample.json` inside your **public** folder and so you can fetch the URL directly:

```js
fetch("sample.json")
  .then(...)
  .then(...)
```

---

Although, you don't need to do all that as you can just import the data like any other js [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

```js
import data from "./sample.json"; // Path

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(item => {
        // return JSX with item...
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-local-json-m414f)** examples.

Comment: Thanks, I moved feed folder to public and it's fixed